# обезопасить строку перед запросом

Tags: php, mysql

На сайте есть форма поиска товаров. Юзер вводит запрос в поле и получает список результатов поиска.

Перед запросом из переменной удаляются кавычки таким способом:

```
$string = str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $_GET['q']);
```

Далее запрос:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE title LIKE '%".$string."%' ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Вопрос собственно такой. Достаточно ли этого для защиты от mysql инъекций например?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, недостаточно.

- При реализации с расширением `mysqli`:

> Нужно использовать функцию [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

- При реализации с расширением `mysql`:

> Использовать функцию [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

---

Обе эти функции в разных расширениях выполняют одно — *экранирует специальные символы в строках для использования в выражениях SQL*

Comment: Расширение `mysql` давным давно протухло. Зря вы его рекомендуете к использованию

Comment: answer changed :)

Comment: Коллеги, ну вот зря вы так... Посмотрите, автор вопроса использует str_replace, а не preg_replace. Скорее всего он будет использовать mysql, а не pdo

Comment: В данном случае и str_replace() хороша.

Comment: А если он в коде будет стрелять себе в ногу? :) К сожалению, большинство спрашивающих не читают UPD (да и вообще текст ответа), а работают по методу "copy-paste". Поэтому, лучше сначала давать наиболее правильный ответ, а потом уже описывать полу-меры с протухшими расширениями.

Comment: Вообще все одновендорные решения протухли с приходом PDO, зачем экранировать строку, если можно ее просто сделать строкой на уровне параметра?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сайт самописный и там везде mysql используется.

Comment: @Arman, перепишите хотя бы с использованием  mysqli. Это не сложно, практически все можно сделать через автозамену строк в редакторе.

Comment: Чтобы все были довольны, поправил ответ)

Comment: @GrayHoax если сделать вот так $string = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);  и затем подставлять в запрос, то  str_replace не нужно ведь уже?

Comment: Нет, не нужно, функция сама поставить экранирование.

Comment: @GrayHoax Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Функция `mysqli_real_escape_string` убирает "не безопасные" значения. Использовать нужно что-то типа:

```
$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcn->idsqlconnection, $string);
```